# Can I set the version scheme to start with zero instead of 1 for an approved document?

Tags: 2010, document-library, publishing, versioning, library

I have many approved documents at revision 0 in an outside database which I would like to migrate/add to a SP library and approve them at SP version 0.  Is there a way to start the approved version at 0 instead of 1?

Answer (score 0):

Version numbers are controlled by the system and there is no OOTB way to change it to 0.I don't think you can change it via coding.

I think may be event receiver works for you but you are going to lower number which i believe not possible at all.